# How to set up medallion architecture in Microsoft Fabric?

Tags: architecture, microsoft-fabric

I am relatively new to Microsoft Fabric and want to create a medallion architecture setup. The documentation is overwhelming.

Is there any way to create a pipeline to go from bronze to gold?